# NGINX - What is the difference between a 'block directive' and a 'context'?

Tags: nginx, webserver, terminology

From NGINX's [Beginner's Guide](http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html), it says:

> A block directive has the same structure as a simple directive, but
>   instead of the semicolon it ends with a set of additional instructions
>   surrounded by braces (`{` and `}`). If a block directive can have other
>   directives inside braces, it is called a context (examples: `events`,
>   `http`, `server`, and `location`).

Therefore, the following entry in the `nginx.conf` can be deemed as both a *block directive* and also a *context*:

```
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}
```

This means a context will always be a block directive, but are there any examples of when a block directive is not a context? If not, does that mean I can use the term 'block directive' and 'context' interchangeably?

Comment: Good, question. Was wondering the same. Did you arrive to a conclusion?

Comment: After almost 3 years, I think it's a matter of perspective - looking from the 'outside', the `events {}` is a block directive. Looking from within the block directive, all the directives inside is in the `events` context. Not an official answer, just my $0.02.

Answer (score 0):

> are there any examples of when a block directive is not a context?

Surely there are `map` and `types`, those can be deemed as block only directives, and not contexts. Because inside them there are *entries*. Although technically those entries are still directives, they by nature have array structure only.

Contexts can include both array-type directives as well as non-array directives (think `fastcgi_param` (array-like directive), and `index` (single entry) in a `location` context).